# Properties of the Riemann zeta function

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, riemann-zeta

I have begun studying the Riemann zeta function $\zeta(s)$, particularly Titchmarsh's book, and have come up with two questions that I have been unable to find an answer to.
They are:

1. Let $c>0$ be a constant and $\sigma_1=\sigma_2>1/2$. Is the function $\dfrac{\zeta(\sigma_1+i(t+c))}{\zeta(\sigma_2+it)}$ analytic?
2. Again, let $\sigma_1=\sigma_2>1/2$. Is there a constant $A>0$ such that $\dfrac{\zeta(\sigma_1+i(t+c))}{\zeta(\sigma_2+it)}<A$ for all $t>t_0>0$?

I believe the answer to be yes to both. The first because $\zeta(s)$ is analytic and the second because by varying $t$ by a bounded amount, I think that the function should be bounded itself.

Comment: what does it mean analytic in your questions? from what it looks like, both numerators and denominator are real functions of $t$ so if you mean real analytic, the answer is that the ratio is not such at zeroes, so the answer to 1 depends on RH; it is well known that regardless of the truth or falsity of RH, $\zeta$ sends each vertical line in $1/2 < \sigma \le 1$ to a dense set in the complex plane, so the second question is false (assuming again you mean something with absolute values and such as the ratio in question is a complex number of course)

Comment: 1. "analytic" as a function of what complex variable?